# NodeJS + TypeORM repository is undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm making a controller and I want to work with repository in my controller as you can see from the snippet below.

```
export class PatientController {
  patientRepository: Repository<Patient>;
  constructor() {
    // Initializing repository
    this.patientRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Patient);
  }
  async getAll(_req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      const patients = await this.patientRepository.find();
      // More logic
    } catch (err: any) {
      // Error logic
    } finally {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

But when I tried it on Postman, it returns

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "message": "Cannot read property 'patientRepository' of undefined"
}
```

Comment: What is transforming this class into an api endpoint? The problem is there, not in your controller class. Whatever is doing that is improperly referencing the instance's methods. It's not that the repository is `undefined`, it's that `this` is undefined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

I guess you may missed using a controller instance.

```js
import express, { Router, Request, Response, Express } from 'express';
import { Column, DataSource, Entity, PrimaryColumn, Repository } from 'typeorm';

// Create Entity
@Entity()
export class Patient {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  message: string;
}

// Create DataSource
const dataSource: DataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: ':memory:',
  synchronize: true,
  entities: [Patient], // Insert entity class
});

// Example
class PatientController {
  private patientRepository: Repository<Patient> = null;
  constructor() {
    // Initializing repository
    this.patientRepository = dataSource.getRepository(Patient);
  }

  async create(entity: Patient): Promise<Patient> {
    return this.patientRepository.save(entity);
  }

  async getAll(_req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    const patients: Patient[] = await this.patientRepository.find();
    console.log(patients); // [ Patient { id: 1, message: 'Hello, World!' } ]
    res.json(patients);
  }
}

// Usage
async function main(): Promise<void> {
  await dataSource.initialize();
  const controller: PatientController = new PatientController();

  // Test data
  const entity: Patient = new Patient();
  entity.message = 'Hello, World!';
  console.log(await controller.create(entity)); // Patient { id: 1, message: 'Hello, World!' }

  // Router
  const router: Router = Router();
  router.get('/patient', (req: Request, res: Response) => controller.getAll(req, res));

  const app: Express = express();
  app.use('/', router);
  app.listen(3000);

  // open http://localhost:3000/patient
}

main();
```